# Do I have to call phpini_set on all pages to set session expiry?

Tags: php

On the host that I'm using, the only way to change the PHP configuration is with `ini_set();` I'm using this to make sessions last for 24 hours:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime','86400');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime','86700');
```

My question is: Do I need those two lines on all pages that call `session_start();` or just the one page I have that sets values initially(ie. the page that sets the cookie)?

Comment: as per my knowledge it will last only per request, better u modifiy in your php.ini, because simple logic ... on next page I can change it....

Comment: Indeed. Find your index.php, which is the first page your application will **always** call on execution and add your `ini_set` directives there. Hint: i might be mistaken, if you are not using a framework/cms.

Comment: prefer to have a *single* entry point (php page) for your app. If you follow that advice, this "all pages" business becomes a non-issue.

Comment: Sorry, I should of included more info. I have a single PHP script on my whole site that sets the session variables, all other pages that call `session_start()` only read the variables. I'm pretty sure I'd only need to include the code to set the expiry in that one PHP script that sets the values as the cookie or session data is not modified on the other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must place ini_set on each page, because [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), only sets the value to the current execution.

For PHP's manual:

> The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's
>   execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

A good idea will be to place all those ini_set's in a seperate file, and require it where ever you need, insted of "copy-pasting" it to all pages, so if you will need to change somthing, you will only have to change it in one file.

If you are using [Front Controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/), you can simpley put it in the front controller file.

Comment: In my particular case, I think I have to only call it in one script. See comment above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595969/do-i-have-to-call-phpini-set-on-all-pages-to-set-session-expiry#comment49261088_30595969

Comment: If that page is called in every request, then there is no problem. You can try to check the expire time of the php session cookie in the browser to see if your code works.